# Silverlight Panels

Tags: silverlight

I currently have two panels with controls on my page and when i set the top to hidden and bottom panel to visible the bottom panel is hovering down the middle of the page.

Is there a way to set this / use another control so that the 2nd panel will go to the top of the page.

thanks

Comment: There are millions of ways how to position two panels on a control. Don't make us guessing.

Comment: Post your xaml code! your issue is pretty difficult to understand as you explain it and its difficult for us to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<StackPanel>
    <local:MyPanel1 Width="300" Height="100" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    <local:MyPanel2 Width="300" Height="100" />
</StackPanel>
```

You can set the panels' visibility in codebehind, or better, databind it to your ViewModel (possibly using a ValueConverter to convert to the Visibility enum).